# Maven - Copy Some Dependency JARs into warSourceDirectory

Tags: maven, applet, war, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

Can any Maven plugins copy one or more dependencies (although not all of them) of a `.war` project into its `warSourceDirectory` (`src/main/webapp`)?

I'm working on a Java web-app that will display an applet. I'd like the war project to pick the latest version of some jars (the applet's dependencies) and stick them in `/src/main/webapp/`, to save me having to copy them around the place.

I've thought about shading and uber-jar-ing the applet itself, but I'd like to split the jars up to save users having to download one massive jar when only one of the bits in it has changed.

Comment: You can use maven-dependency-plugin either with `copy` or `copy-dependencies` goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for this [dependency:copy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) from [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).

Read also example page: [Copying specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html)

Sample configuration

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.8</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                    <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Copying files into `src/main/webapp` is bad idea. Copy file directly into `target` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I tweaked your answer to use `artifactId` rather than `artifact`. If you add the full plugin configuration from my answer I'll happily mark yours as definitive.